# MySQL - DATE_ADD month interval by each month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have written a function below to give me the number of jobs an employee has done in a particular 30 day period (each ID in the 'jobs column' of the table represents 1 job).

the function work fine if I only want to look back 4 week. the problem however is that I want the count to start at the beginning of each month. for example, if a person views the records on the 10th December 2013 I need the records to show all the work for December (but not the records for the preceding 30 days).

**Below is my function:**

```
 $interval_1month = 'interval 4 WEEK';

function statsHowMuchWorkDoneByStaff ($staff_id, $timeInterval)
    {
        global $dbc;

    $select = " SELECT 
                    COUNT(job_id) AS totalnumberWork ";

    $from   = " FROM 
                staffwork 
                    ";

     $where = " WHERE
                        staff_id = $staff_id
                    AND  
                        FROM_UNIXTIME(entrytime) >= now() -  $timeInterval";    

    $query  = $select.$from. $where;

    $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)
                 or trigger_error("Query:  $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));     

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
        {
           $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

           $result  = safe_output($row['totalnumbernewcontacts']) ;

           return $result ; 
        }
        else
        {
           return false; 
        }
    }
```

Any advise on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: here is my datatable:**

```
CREATE TABLE staffwork(
staff_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
job_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

data_table VARCHAR (65) NOT NULL, 
entrytime int(11) NOT NULL, 

INDEX message (staff_id) 

);
```

Comment: are you getting an error? or just unexpected results? please provide table structure and sample data

Comment: Hello Nrathaus. thanks for reply. the result is as expected. however, i a trying to modify the results. i.e i want the results to just give me the results for a particular month: at the moment, the function returns data for the preceding 4 wek period, but i want the results for a particular month.

Comment: Why not receive from the user the value of ``now()`` and not use ``now()`` all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you want to calculate `COUNT(job_id)` for a specific month by supplying any date of that month as a parameter, then you can do it this way

```sql
SELECT COUNT(job_id) total
  FROM staffwork
 WHERE staff_id = 1
   AND entrytime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY('2013-12-10') + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   AND entrytime <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY('2013-12-10') + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

**Note:** This query is index friendly because it doesn't convert `entrytime` to datetime but rather convert range values (which are constants for the query) to unix time. **Make sure that you have indices on `entrytime` and `staff_id`** to be able to take advantage of that.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bfc9/8)** demo

---

And while you're at it consider to learn and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings leaving your code vulnerable for sql injections.

That being said your php function might look like this

```php
function statsWorkDoneByStaffMember($staff_id, $month) {
    global $dbc;

    $sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(job_id) total
      FROM staffwork
     WHERE staff_id = ?
       AND entrytime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(?) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
       AND entrytime <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(?) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ";

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    if (!$stmt) {
        trigger_error('Prepare failed: ' . $dbc->error); 
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $staff_id, $month, $month);
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        trigger_error('Execute failed: ' . $dbc->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    return $result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$dbc = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
$staff_id = 1;

//Get the number of job_id for the current month
$total = statsWorkDoneByStaffMember($staff_id, date('Y-m-d'));

//Get the number of job_id for a specific month
$total = statsWorkDoneByStaffMember($staff_id, '2013-07-01');
```